# How to find x-value of maximum in a certain range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

How can I determine the x-value of a maximum of a data set within a certain range?

For context, these records the datasets look like this:

- `value['Wavelength']`:

  ```
  PixelNo
  0       1167.467506
  1       1167.219570
  2       1166.971628
  3       1166.723680
  4       1166.475725
             ...     
  3635     233.904486
  3636     233.641110
  3637     233.377731
  3638     233.114350
  3639     232.850967
  Name: Wavelength, Length: 3640, dtype: float64
  ```
- `value['Calib_1']`:

  ```
  PixelNo
  0       1.000000e+00
  1       5.500000e+01
  2       3.500000e+01
  3       1.000000e-07
  4       4.600000e+01
              ...     
  3635    4.000000e+01
  3636    7.400000e+01
  3637    1.000000e-07
  3638    3.000000e+00
  3639    1.600000e+01
  Name: Calib_1, Length: 3640, dtype: float64
  ```

This is an example of the corresponding plot of all data sets.

[image: Plot]

Comment: not clear what you mean, but np.max() not working ?

Comment: @karl, do you mean the index of the maximum value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `argmax` method which returns the index of the maximum value.
Let's suppose you have a curve like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


value = pd.DataFrame({'Wavelength': np.linspace(250, 600, 10000)})
value['Calib_1'] = (np.sin(2*np.pi/20*value['Wavelength'])*np.exp(-(value['Wavelength']-455)**2/20/(600-250)))**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(value['Wavelength'], value['Calib_1'], color = 'blue')

ax.set_xlabel('Wavelength')
ax.set_ylabel('Calib_1')

plt.show()
```

[image]

The above curve is designed to have a maximum in `455`.
You can find the index of the maximum with:

```
value['Calib_1'].argmax()
# 5857
```

and use it to get the corresponding x axis value through `loc` method:

```
value.loc[value['Calib_1'].argmax(), 'Wavelength']
# 455.015501550155
```

As you can see, it returns a value approximately close to the exact value of `455`. The error is to be addressed to the x axis discretization with `numpy.linspace`.
You can plot the maximum on the above plot with:

```
id_max = value['Calib_1'].argmax()
x_max = value.loc[id_max, 'Wavelength']
y_max = value.loc[id_max, 'Calib_1']


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(value['Wavelength'], value['Calib_1'], color = 'blue')
ax.plot(x_max, y_max, marker = 'o', color = 'red')

ax.set_xlabel('Wavelength')
ax.set_ylabel('Calib_1')

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you need a maximum only on a specific range, let's say `[500, 550]`, then first of all you have to filter the dataframe, then compute the index of the maximum:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


value = pd.DataFrame({'Wavelength': np.linspace(250, 600, 10000)})
value['Calib_1'] = (np.sin(2*np.pi/20*value['Wavelength'])*np.exp(-(value['Wavelength']-455)**2/20/(600-250)))**2

value_filt = value[(value['Wavelength'] >= 500) & (value['Wavelength'] <= 550)].reset_index()
id_max = value_filt['Calib_1'].argmax()
x_max = value_filt.loc[id_max, 'Wavelength']
y_max = value_filt.loc[id_max, 'Calib_1']


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(value['Wavelength'], value['Calib_1'], color = 'blue')
ax.plot(x_max, y_max, marker = 'o', color = 'red')

ax.axvline(x = 500, color = 'black', linestyle = '--')
ax.axvline(x = 550, color = 'black', linestyle = '--')

ax.set_xlabel('Wavelength')
ax.set_ylabel('Calib_1')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: and how to find within an interval the peaks that exceed a certain value?

Comment: When compute `value_filt` by filtering, you should add the condition `... & (value['Calib_1'] >= threshold)`, where `threshold` is your certain value. The the filer becomes `value_filt = value[(value['Wavelength'] >= 500) & (value['Wavelength'] <= 550) & (value['Calib_1'] >= threshold)].reset_index()`